# what does % sign mean in python

Tags: python, testing, numbers, sign

**what does % sign mean in python?** 
I looked it up and it said that it's a format for the print part, but it's not on the part of the printing so it didn't really help..
here's the code anyway:

```
a = 5
b = 6
c = 7
for i in range((a+b)*4):
  if i%c == 0:
    print(i)
```

Comment: its the modulo operator https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/modulus.html

Answer (score 2):

The % is the modulo it will return the rest of an euclidian division

Ex :

```py
10 % 3 == 1 #True because 10//3 = 9 and the rest is 1
10 % 10 == 0 #True because 10//10 = 1 and the rest is 0
```

Answer (score 2):

It denotes a Modulus operator; gives the remainder of the left value divided by the right value.
like:

```
5%3=2

15%30=15
```